# Node.js - How to apply filter and text search on populated fields in MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-populate

```
const parentSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  childId: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "Child"
  }
});

const childSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }
});

const results = await Parent.find().populate("clientId", "email, name");
```

1. How to apply filter on "email" such that a particular child with given "email" is populated?
2. How to apply text search on "name" of the child ?

Comment: I assume you're supposed to use `await`, not `awair`?

Comment: yes await. It was a typo

Comment: You asked two different questions in one question, you had better to ask a seperate question for text search.

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to use `aggregate` to achieve this, see code below

```
Parent.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: 'child',
            let: {
                email_: "abc@example.com",
                childId_: '$childId'
            },
            pipeline: [
                {
                    $match: {
                        $expr: {
                            $and: [
                                {
                                    $eq: ['$email', '$$email_']
                                },
                                {
                                    $eq: ['$_id', '$$childId_']
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            as: 'child'
        }
    },{
        $unwind:'$child'
    },{
        $match:{
            'child.name':{
                $regex: "SearchKeyWord",
                $options: 'i' // For case insensitive search
            }
        }
    }
]);
```

Here, we first populate only `child` having specified `email_id` using `$lookup`

Then, we use regex to filter the `child` based on search keyword (I have used case insensitive)

Now, this will give you list of all children with respective parents like `[{parent_field_1:parent_value_1,......, child:{child_object}}]`

If you want to all children of same parents, you can use `$group` in your subsequent projection